# How to measure Docker startup time

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot

I'm buiding a docker image from a jar file ( Spring Boot application), but  I could not use the  command `time docker run my-image` to check the startup time of the container. Because of the output from Spring Boot, the `docker run` command will not stop.

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/app.jar" ]
```

Is there other way to measure the startup time of the container?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the `time` command you have tried? If you're trying to measure the amount of time your Spring Boot application takes to startup then `docker run` is the wrong place to start

Comment: I tried `time docker run my-image`

Comment: See comment above - what you're trying with `time` will only tell you how long the `docker run` command took (probably very fast) but won't tell you how long your Spring app took to launch

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Spring Boot's output log actually shows how long does it take to start the appplication.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this. What are you actually trying to measure the time of?

Comment: @timothyclifford: I'm trying to test the startup time of a containerized application and compare it with a bare JAR app.